# Program for activity selection exceeds time limit

Tags: c++, performance, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded, memory-optimization

I've been trying to solve this problem for some while and the solution I have come up with exceeds the lime limit by 1-3 ms and 2 out of 10 tests get a memory issue error. Why is that? This is the code for my solution:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

ifstream in("planificare.in");
ofstream out("planificare.out");

struct show {
    int start, finish, used = 0;
};

bool end_time (show lhs, show rhs) {
    if (lhs.finish == rhs.finish) return lhs.start < rhs.start;
    return lhs.finish < rhs.finish;
}

int main() {
    int participants, tv_chan;
    vector<show> prog;
    in >> participants >> tv_chan;
    for (int i = 1; i <= participants; i++) {
        show a;
        in >> a.start >> a.finish;
        prog.push_back(a);
    }
    sort(prog.begin(), prog.end(), end_time);
    int maxActivities = 0;
    int unused = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= tv_chan; i++) {
        while (prog[unused].used)
            unused++;
        int lastFinish = prog[unused].finish;
        prog[unused].used = 1;
        maxActivities ++;
        for (int j = 0; j < prog.size(); j++) {
            if (prog[j].start >= lastFinish && prog[j].used == 0) {
                maxActivities++;
                lastFinish = prog[j].finish;
                prog[j].used = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    out << maxActivities;
}
```

### [Planificare - InfoArena](https://infoarena.ro/problema/planificare)

> *Talent Day* is coming soon at the Blomkvist TV channel and the CEO Mike
>   needs you to make the program grid. \$N\$ participants have enrolled
>   to expose their talents, each communicating the amount of time it
>   needs. Mike's TV Chain consists of \$K\$ stations, (Blomkvist 1, Blomkvist 2,
>   ... Blomkvist K) that transmit independently of each other. Due to the
>   fact that all \$K\$ stations are all just as popular as the other, the participants are indifferent
>   to which they will appear.
>
> Knowing that at any given moment any station
>   will broadcast a single show, determining the maximum number of shows
>   that can be televised.
>
> ### Input data
>
> The input file `planificare.in` will contain on the first line \$2\$ natural numbers: \$N\$
>   and \$K\$. On each of the following \$N\$ lines there will be 2 values,
>   the starting time and the end time, representing the time interval during which the
>   participant performs its activity.
>
> ### Output data
>
> The output file `planificare.out` will contain the number requested by Mike on
>   the first line.
>
> ### Restrictions and clarifications
>
> \$1 \le N \le 100,000\$
>
> \$1 \le K \le 100,000\$
>
> \$1 \le \text{start}_i \le \text{stop}_i \le 1,000,000,000\$
>
> ### Time limit: 0.2 seconds
>
> For **30%** of the tests, \$N\$ ≤ 2000 and for another **10%** of the tests, \$K\$ = 1.
>      At each channel, a show can start at the same time that the previous one is over.
>
> ### Example
>
> ***`planificare.in`***
>
> ```
> 2 1
> 1 4
> 4 8
> ```
>
> ***`planificare.out`***
>
> ```
> 2
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with a friend, I ended up with this code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

ifstream in("planificare.in");
ofstream out("planificare.out");

int main() {
    int participants, tv_chan;
    vector<pair<int, int> > prog;
    in >> participants >> tv_chan;
    for (int i = 1; i <= participants; i++) {
        int s, f;
        in >> s >> f;
        prog.push_back(make_pair(f, s));
    }

    sort(prog.begin(), prog.end());

    int maxActivities = 0;
    multiset<int> actFinish;
    for (int i = 1; i <= tv_chan; i++) {
        actFinish.insert(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < participants; i++) {

        multiset<int>::iterator it = actFinish.lower_bound(prog[i].second);
        if (it == actFinish.end()) it--;
        if (*it > prog[i].second && it != actFinish.begin()) it--;

        if (*it <= prog[i].second) {
            maxActivities++;
            actFinish.erase(it);
            actFinish.insert(prog[i].first);
        }
    }
    out << maxActivities;
}
```

`Multiset` is for storing more of the same elements, `lower_bound` returns the `iterator` to the first element in my `multiset` that is *greater or equal* than the specified `begin_time`.

The first `if` is to reduce the `iterator`, if it's more than the number of elements in my `multiset` and the second one is to reduce the `iterator`, if the number in the `mutliset` represented by `it` is greater than the specified `begin_time`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are erasing elements from `prog` and then without bounds checking access it with `prog[j]`. That is sure to fall over.

Your `end_time` function is commonly known as `operator<` So you should use the appropriate name.

There is no comment on the significance of `1` and why a program should not be reordered when it starts at `1`. It seems that different programs with starting time `1` should still have an ordering.

You are inconsistent in your loops. Once goes from `1` to `<= participants` the other goes from `0` to `< participants`. The latter is the commonly used one.

The first loop seems to sort for start time? You can achieve the same if you create a proper `operator<`.

`using namespace std;` is bad practice. There is no benefit to it other that you do not really know what is standard and what not, which is actually bad. Also it isprone to name clashes. Use what you need and not everything `C++` has in the box

Comment: Thanks! This was helpful! However, I use `namespace std` for conveniency, as I don't need to remove it in this current program - no functions created by me interfere with `std` ones. Inconsistency in the loops comes from the fact that I was taught to go from `1` to `<= limit` and that's what I've used for 3-4 years since I'm into programming and changing that habit can be hard and useless, if the loop I'm used to works fine. When it doesn't, I know I can go from `0` to `< limit`. One question remains unanswered, however. Why the *time limit exceeded error* ?

Comment: Also, the first loop takes the activities that start at moment `1` and puts them in the first positions.

Comment: And I used the `bool end_time` function for conveniece, again, as I don't need to overload an operator necesarily.

Comment: @antoniu200 Unfortunately you are factually wrong. First, there is no `operator<` defined. Until spaceship comes you have to write them manually. Second, you are sorting the array twice with respect to different proerties of your struct. You can sort it just once by using a better comparison function. Third there is no convinience won using `end_time`. `operator<` is not really longer and you wouldnt have to pass it to std::sort. Finally, `using namespace std;` is always bad. For such a tiny example fine, but in bigger project it will bite you. Why learn bad stuff?